# How do you develop a plugin for Apache Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I've been trying to use the documentation [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).

But it doesn't start very helpfully. It assumes that the plugin will be in a git repo, which I can't do due to development environment constraints.

1. Where does a custom plugin go in a Cordova project?
2. Does a git repo HAVE to be used?
3. What needs to be added to the various config.xml files?

I'm using Apache Cordova-3.4.0 and I hope to develop the plugin for the android platform first.

There may be more questions, but lets start with that.
All the guides on the internet currently seem quite outdated so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can create a git repo on disk. It doesn't need to be on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [plugman](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html) utility in order to create the default structure of your plugin, for each platform, and then use the cordova tool to add that plugin to the project.

Install the plugman tool and then follow it's help for the "plugman create" command, and then add the platform of your choice to the plugin.

This should auto-generate an echo plugin, which you are now free to edit and install using:
"cordova plugin add ".

You can then access the plugin using "cordova.plugin.plugin-name" in your javascript.